# correct the award of a bounty

Tags: support

I recently start a bounty for a question, but award it to the answer that not the best, then is there any way to correct this?

I don't know where to ask this question (and I don't think this is the right place), but any way, help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* the right place to ask such a question, accepting that it is not private at least.

Neither users nor community moderators are able to reverse the awarding of a Bounty.  Further, it is likely that what you want is specifically undesirable by which I mean that it is intended behavior that the Bounty cannot be reversed; if a Bounty *could* be reversed it would provide far less incentive for someone to post a timely answer thereby significantly reducing its value.

- If you awarded a Bounty to an answer that you now know to be in error I suggest you note that in a comment under the answer or possibly in a footnote to your question itself.
- If you simply feel that a new answer is better there is no problem; the Bounty system worked as intended and you should be glad you *also* got the new answer.  You can award a second Bounty if you feel the need to do so as a matter of justice.
- If you awarded the Bounty accidentally then I suggest more care in the future, because there are confirmation dialogs on this operation to help prevent mistakes.